# How to append results into a column in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to merge two intput files to produce the below output data using the below script but don't know how to add results into a the second column:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read gene number
do
    while read gene2 type
    do
    if [ "$gene" = "$gene2" ]
    then
    echo -e "$gene\t$number\t$type" >>output.txt
    elif [ "$gene" = "$type" ]
    then
    ??? add the numbers in the second column >>output.txt
    fi
    done<in2.txt
done<in1.txt
```

here are my input files:

in1.txt:

```
gene1   30
gene2   20
f   1
e   2
```

in2.txt:

```
gene1   f
gene2   e
```

desired output:

output.txt:

```
gene1   30  f  1
gene2   20  e  2
```

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: Have a look at the `join` command.

Comment: Its tab spaced @Cyrus

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and two associative arrays (in1, in2):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A in1 in2

# read both files in associative arrays
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do in1[$key]="$value"; done < in1.txt
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do in2[$key]="$value"; done < in2.txt

# if necessary show both associative arrays
#declare -p in1 in2

# iterate over keys of associative array in2 and output data
for i in "${!in2[@]}"; do
  echo -e "$i\t${in1[$i]}\t${in2[$i]}\t${in1[${in2[$i]}]}"
done
```

Output:

```
gene2   20      e       2
gene1   30      f       1
```